# get_query_var() and permalinks

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, templates, categories

I have a permalink structure that looks like this,

%category%/%postname%

I have a category.php template coded up and and trying to pull of the post of a certain category, so for example my URL may look like this,

/category/category1

I want all posts that are in category1 to be return however, when using the following code I get null returned,

`get_query_var('cat')`

I assume that this code is looking for URL that looks like this,

?cat=category1

So how do I make it work with permalinks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress rewrites rules invisibly translate pretty permalinks to the non-pretty format internally, and set the appropriate variables and load the requested page, you don't need to do anything in your template to load posts from a category on a category page.

The `cat` query var specifically will be set to the *ID* of the requested category, not the name.

That said, this:

```
$my_category = get_query_var('cat');
echo $my_category;
```

*should* print the selected category ID on a category page. If it's not, we'd have to see your code to help you further.

Also, have a look at the `$wp_query` global to see all query vars set on a particular page:

```
global $wp_query
print_r($wp_query);
```

Comment: Where exactly does the query_var show up in the print_r($wp_query)?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me get my answer, the problem I found was that the object from

```
global $wp_query
```

didn't contain a category id if permalinks were turned on. However it did contain a category name, thus to retrieve the category id the following code worked for me.

```
$category = get_query_var('category_name');
$categoryid = array(get_cat_ID( $category ));
```

this is particularly useful with `pre_get_posts`

Comment: The reason might be that you have overwritten the main query. Please update your question and show us how your main query is built.